# “1–2 minutes” or “1–2 minute(s)”

Tags: grammatical-number

If we are using both singular and plural in the same sentence, how do we say or write it?

For example, which one is correct?

1. one to two minutes
2. one to two minute(s)
3. one minute to two minutes

Comment: "one to two minutes" -- however, try asking such Qs on ell.stackexchange.com rather than ELU.

Comment: @Kris: is it correct to form the noun according the the latest number, eg. "one to two eggs" and "two or one egg"?

Comment: @Truong Ha: It's weird to say "two or one egg": it'd have to be "two eggs or one". You could say "one egg or two" instead of "one to two eggs", though.

Comment: Think of it this way: "How many minutes?" The answer could even be "One minute." Here, the reference in the question is to the quantum of time, always plural (in minutes) when the quantum is **unknown**. Likewise in a statement, the quantum is expressed in the plural by default, except where the quantum is definitely known to be singular. " *One minute*, *half a minute*, *two minutes*, but *one or two **minutes*** ." HTH.

Comment: It is not dependent on the adjacent/ nearest noun. Hypothetically, if at all you wanted to say "two or one ...," it would be "two or one eggs," plural, as I said above.

Comment: Something similar comes up all the time in discussions of (U.S.) dimensions of cell phones and other small electronic devices. Consider this sentence: "The Samsung Galaxy S4 measures 5.38 by 2.75 by 0.31 inches." You could avoid ending with "0.31 inches" (if it bothered you) by explicitly attaching "inches" to the first two measurements: "5.38 inches by 2.75 inches by 0.31 inch." But you can't (in my opinion) attribute "inch" to the two measurements that exceed 1 inch, as happens with the phrasing "5.38 by 2.75 by 0.31 inch." I think that Kris's analysis of this point is correct.

Comment: @SvenYargs However, there's also a practice in technical writing of using the singular as the standard for units mentioned after the quantity (this is a different case from the OP's). Length: 11 inch; Weight: 40 pound; Quantity 4 number. Odd as it may be, there's a reason and justification for that. ...

Comment: "5.38 by 2.75 by 0.31 inch." or "5.38 inch by 2.75 inch by 0.31 inch." are both acceptable, too.

Comment: @Kris Nope, that’s completely wrong: you need to use *inches* in the plural.

Comment: @tchrist & 1 more. Lol. Take your time to learn. Sorry if that sounds harsh but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

The plural is used to designate any non-singular quantity, including indefinite amounts.

E.g.

1. **negative**: I have negative two dollars.
2. **zero**: I have zero dollars
3. **singular**: I have one dollar
4. **plural**: I have four dollars. I have two and a half dollars.
5. **indefinite**: I have several dollars.

You may also express amounts in English using the partitive genitive (e.g. a quarter of a donut), in which case the whole and not the parts determine the number. So I may have a "quarter of a dollar" or "an eighth of two dollars."

Also, collectives often take a singular verb, especially in American English.

both "The Government is a governing body" and "The Government are a governing body" are correct, although the first is more common in America and the second in the UK.

All that to say that while you would always use the plural "dollars" when talking of 1-2 dollars, you may use either a singular or a plural verb according to whether the dollars are considered one thing or many.

1. 1-2 dollars is enough for a candy-bar
2. 1-2 dollars are enough for a candy-bar